# Trying to return a function from a function with an argument function within it

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I am curious if that's even possible to create a static function in another function and then return that static function with an argument function within it. So far what I've tried doesn't work at all, and when I use raw function pointers the code fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//both do not work but this one doesn't even compile
/*
void (*func(void (*foo)()))()
{
    static void (*copy)();
    copy = [&]() { foo(); };
    return copy;
}
*/

std::function<void(void)> Foo(std::function<void(void)> func)
{
    static std::function<void(void)> temp = [&]() { func(); };
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Foo([]() { std::cout << 123 << '\n'; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your commented `func` is that a lambda which captures anything cannot convert to a pointer to function. Lambda captures provide data saved at initialization to be used when called, and a plain C++ function does not have any data other than its passed arguments. This capability is actually one of the big reasons `std::function` is helpful and we don't just use function pointers for what it does. `std::function` is more powerful than a function pointer.

Of course, `func` could instead just do `copy = foo`; or just `return foo;`, avoiding the lambda issue.

One problem with `Foo` is that the lambda captures function parameter `func` by reference, and then is called after `Foo` has returned and the lifetime of `func` has ended. A lambda which might be called after the scope of its captures is over should not capture them by reference, and `std::function` is an easy way to get into that bad situation. The lambda should use `[=]` or `[func]` instead.

Note that your `static` inside `Foo` is not like the `static` in front of an actual function declaration. It makes `temp` a function-static variable, which is initialized only the very first time and then kept. If `Foo` is called a second time with a different lambda, it will return the same thing it did the first time. If that's not what you want, just drop that `static`. Linkage of the functions/variables is not an issue here.

(It's a bit strange that `Foo` puts a `std::function` inside a lambda inside a `std::function` which all just directly call the next, instead of just using the original `std::function`. But I'll assume that's just because it's a simplified or learning-only example. If the lambda did something additional or different, this would be a fine way to do it.)

Your `main` ignores the function returned from `Foo`. Maybe you meant to call what `Foo` returns, with

```
int main()
{
    Foo([]() { std::cout << 123 << '\n'; })();
}
```

Comment: Very informative answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It works, you simply never **invoke** the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void(void)> Foo(std::function<void(void)> func)
{
    static std::function<void(void)> temp = [&]() { func(); };
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    // Notice final `()`
    Foo([]() { std::cout << 123 << '\n'; })();
}
```

But you are capturing the function by reference, so you have to make sure the capturer doesn't outlive it.
Otherwise you could copy capture it.